# How to merge elasticsearch indices

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, elasticsearch-indices

In Elasticsearch v7.12.0 I have several indices named as `payload.YYYY-MM`.
With `YYYY` = year and `MM` = month.

In order to reduce the amount of indices, I would like to merge all the indices that are from the same year in a new indice named `payload.YYYY`

How can I do it using the Elasticsearch API ?

(I don't  want to use the aliases as it doesn't reduce the amount of indices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very simply using the [`_reindex` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) and running the following command for each year you want to support:

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "payload.2022-*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "payload.2022"
  }
}
```

All indexes named `payload.2022-*` will be reindexed into the yearly index `payload.2022`. Make sure to create the yearly index with the same mapping as the monthly indexes prior to running the command.

Note: adding `wait_for_completion=false` makes the command create a task in the background and return immediately with a task ID. You can then use that task ID to monitor the process in the background using

```
GET _tasks/<task_id>
```